# spring hibernate hibernate.connection.provider_class is not getting invoke

Tags: spring, hibernate, connection-pooling

I m using spring 3 and hibernate 3.x and mule 3.x in my application.My config file is

```
<spring:bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <spring:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <spring:property name="packagesToScan" value="${hibernate.packagesToScan}" />
            <spring:property name="eventListeners">
                <spring:map>
                    <spring:entry key="pre-insert">
                        <spring:bean
                            class="com.myapp.listener.PreInsertOrUpdateEventListener"
                            id="preInsertOrUpdateEventListener" />
                    </spring:entry>
                    <spring:entry key="pre-update">
                        <spring:bean
                            class="com.myapp.listener.PreInsertOrUpdateEventListener"
                            id="preInsertOrUpdateEventListener" />
                    </spring:entry>
                </spring:map>
            </spring:property>
            <spring:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <spring:props>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">${hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">${hibernate.connection.provider_class}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">${hibernate.dbcp.initialSize}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.dbcp.maxActive">${hibernate.dbcp.maxActive}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">${hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle}
                    </spring:prop>
                    <spring:prop key="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">${hibernate.dbcp.minIdle}
                    </spring:prop>
                </spring:props>
            </spring:property>
        </spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="dataSource" name="dataSource"
            class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <spring:property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
            <spring:property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
            <spring:property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
            <spring:property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        </spring:bean>
```

I want to invoke my custom connection provider class for connection pooling but it is not getting called. can anybody pls tell me what is the issue..

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

`AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` and `LocalSessionFactoryBean` replaces connection provider with spring provided `LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider`. So either you have to use it or create your own customized `LocalSessionFactoryBean` by extending it.

Check `LocalSessionFactoryBean` source code to see how its setting the `connectionProvider` value.

Hope it helps. I'm also looking for a good solution to this.

Comment: yes i have seen the source code and it is doing the same and the solution that i found is very simple. just remove the separete entry for BasicDataSource and add all its properties in hibernte SessionFactory implementation itself and you can use custom connection provider in ur application...

Comment: @Atanu Pal Your analysis is correct, the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean overwrites the hibernateProperties that are provided in the config file (I verified the source). I solved my problem by implementing a DelegatingDataSource which wraps the original datasource to configure the connections, so in my case I did not need the provider anymore.